# Repeated Single Regression w/ Factor and Continuous Variables

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

I have a dataset similar to the below structure that I'd like to run several single regressions with:

```
example <- tibble(
  id = paste0('ID', runif(100,0,10)),
  response = runif(100,0,10),
  x1 = runif(100,0,10),
  x2 = factor(rep(seq(1,5),20)))

regression_1 <- lm(response ~ x1, data = example)
regression_2 <- lm(response ~ x2, data = example)
```

And so on for n predictors. I've tried a variety of approaches but I keep running into an error and cannot figure out for the life of me any neat and easy way to do this.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Using `reformulate`.

```
lapply(c("x1", "x2", "xn"), function(x) lm(reformulate(x, response="response"), d))
# [[1]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = reformulate(x, response = "response"), data = d)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           x1  
#       0.03567      0.03603  
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = reformulate(x, response = "response"), data = d)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           x2  
#       0.03098     -0.14824  
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = reformulate(x, response = "response"), data = d)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           xn  
#       0.02961      0.08823
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
d <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(400), 100, 4, dimnames=list(NULL, c("response", "x1", "x2", "xn"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can subset the data and use `~ .`

```
lapply(c("x1", "x2", "xn"), function(x) lm(response ~ ., df1[c('response', x)]))
```